# Self closing Html Generic Control?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, htmlgenericcontrol

I am writing a bit of code to add a link tag to the head tag in the code behind... i.e.

```
HtmlGenericControl css = new HtmlGenericControl("link");

css.Attributes["rel"] = "Stylesheet";
css.Attributes["type"] = "text/css";
css.Attributes["href"] = String.Format("/Assets/CSS/{0}", cssFile);
```

to try and achieve something like...

```
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/CSS/Blah.css" />
```

I am using the HtmlGenericControl to achieve this... the issue I am having is that the control ultimatly gets rendered as...

```
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/CSS/Blah.css"></link>
```

I cant seem to find what I am missing to not render the additional `</link>`, I assumed it should be a property on the object.

Am I missing something or is this just not possible with this control?

Comment: Any particular reason you want the short form? For one or maybe a handful of links per page I think the overhead of a handful of bytes would be negligible.

Comment: Because using the long form of some tags causes problems in some browser. It's a good idea. Some versions (perhaps all?) of IE don't cope with <br></br>

Comment: @Lazarus: erikkallen is correct with the browser issue, I want to ensure the best compatibility.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you'd have to derive from `HtmlGenericControl`, and override the `Render` method.

You'll then be able to write out the "/>" yourself (or you can use HtmlTextWriter's `SelfClosingTagEnd` constant).

Edit: [Here's an example](http://forums.asp.net/p/1118661/1742985.aspx#1742985) (in VB)

Answer (score 9):

While trying to write a workaround for `umbraco.library:RegisterStyleSheetFile(string key, string url)` I ended up with the same question as the OP and found the following.

According to the [specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#void-elements), the **link** tag is a void element. It cannot have any content, but can be self closing. The W3C validator did not validate `<link></link>` as correct html5.

Apparently

```
HtmlGenericControl css = new HtmlGenericControl("link");
```

is rendered by default as `<link></link>`. Using the specific control for the **link** tag solved my problem:

```
HtmlLink css = new HtmlLink();
```

It produces the mark-up `<link/>` which was validated as correct xhtml and html5.

In addition to **link**, [System.Web.UI.HtmlControls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols) contains classes for other void element controls, such as **img**, **input** and **meta**.

Comment: This is clearly the cleanest way to produce valid html...why use generic control when an HtmlLink class is provided?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use `Page.ParseControl(string)`, which gives you a control with the same contents as the string you pass.

I'm actually doing this exact same thing in my current project. Of course it requires a reference to the current page, (the handler), but that shouldn't pose any problems.

The only caveat in this method, as I see it, is that you don't get any "OO"-approach for creating your control (eg. `control.Attributes.Add("href", theValue")` etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I just created a solution for this, based on Ragaraths comments in another forum:

http://forums.asp.net/p/1537143/3737667.aspx

Override the HtmlGenericControl with this

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    if (this.Controls.Count > 0)
        base.Render(writer); // render in normal way
    else
    {
        writer.Write(HtmlTextWriter.TagLeftChar + this.TagName); // render opening tag
        Attributes.Render(writer); // Add the attributes.  
        writer.Write(HtmlTextWriter.SelfClosingTagEnd); // render closing tag   
    }

    writer.Write(Environment.NewLine); // make it one per line
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The *slightly* hacky way.

- Put the control inside a PlaceHolder element.
- In the code behind hijack the render method of the PlaceHolder.
- Render the PlaceHolders content exactly as you wish.

This is page / control specific and does not require any overrides. So it has minimal impact on the rest of your system.

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="myPlaceHolder" runat="server">
    <hr id="someElement" runat="server" />
</asp:PlaceHolder>

protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myPlaceHolder.SetRenderMethodDelegate(ClosingRenderMethod);
}

protected void ClosingRenderMethod(HtmlTextWriter output, Control container)
{
    var voidTags = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) { "br", "hr", "link", "img" };
    foreach (Control child in container.Controls)
    {
        var generic = child as HtmlGenericControl;
        if (generic != null && voidTags.Contains(generic.TagName))
        {                
            output.WriteBeginTag(generic.TagName);
            output.WriteAttribute("id", generic.ClientID);
            generic.Attributes.Render(output);
            output.Write(HtmlTextWriter.SelfClosingTagEnd);                
        }
        else
        {
            child.RenderControl(output);
        }
    }
}
```