# HtmlGenericControl("img") not generating proper image tag

Tags: c#, asp.net

in asp.net, I'm trying to generate an image tag with:

```
var img = new HtmlGenericControl("img");
```

it seems to generate `<img></img>`

How would I generate a normal image tag with asp.net/C#?

e.g.

```
<img/>
```

Comment: Semantically `<img></img>` is the same as `<img/>` so why does it matter?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Self closing Html Generic Control?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708037/self-closing-html-generic-control)

Comment: @Bala R, you're correct, it is a similar issue. I'd like to think this question is specific enough to remain. Upon observing the first answer, it seems that using HtmlGenericControl is not the best way to create img tags.

Comment: @Bala R, in my specific use case, IE6 and 7 don't behave consistently when using <img></img> vs <img/>

Comment: I see. In that case you'll have to create a subclass from `HtmlGenericControl` and override `Render` as shown in this post http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/aspnetcontrols/a-self-closing-htmlgenericcontrol

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a specialized html control for the image element.

```
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlImage
```

which generates the html you want.

Comment: this seems like the easiest fix. I just changed each instance of `HtmlGenericControl("img")` to `HtmlImage()` and everything worked as planned. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are creating it as a generic html control.  Try using the Image control:

```
var img = new Image();
```

Comment: Note: this is `System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image` and not `System.Drawing.Image`.

Comment: I think his issue was <tag></tag> not <tag/> and not the specific type of control created.

Comment: I'm sure, but the HtmlGenericControl doesn't understand what the <img> tag is and simply creates the standard open and close tag.

Answer (score 1):

Override the rendering method and use HtmlTextWriter.SelfClosingTagEnd to create a self closing tag?